# Infopath and Cascading Dropdowns

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, infopath2010, cascadingdropdown

I have a question for you bright minded souls. I have an Infopath form for a Sharepoint List (meaning that this is considered an Infopath List Form) that I would like certain behavior for... and I'm not quite sure how to achieve it.

The gist is, I have two dropdowns on the form and I want the second dropdown to change its values based on the first dropdowns selection.

Both are pointing at the same list. The list looks like so:

```
ID, ModuleName, SystemName, PayCode, LineOfBusoness
1, Mod1, Sys1, O, LOB1 
2, Mod2, Sys2, O, LOB2
3, Mod3, Sys3, C, LOB3
4, Mod3, Sys4, O, LOB3
```

The first dropdown contains just the paycodes, so basically "O", and "C".

Now the second dropdown is where it gets tricky.

The second drop down is to display all the Lines of Business (LOB) from that list based on the PayCode selected in the previous dropdown. If they select "O" then just display all the LOBs that has the paycode of "O".

BUT... if they select "C"... well then there are also dropdowns on the form where they have already selected System and Module... so it would then take those values that were selected and choose the value in the list that has the System they chose, the Module they chose, and the Paycode they chose.

How can I do that? My first thought was well, just use code... but it turns out Infopath does not allow custom code on a "list form" which this is... wtf? So then the next option is to use the "cascading dropdown" approach whereby you can also use rules and filters to try and achieve this behavior.

Can that be done? What are your thoughts as to how you would tackle this problem?

Thanks in advance, and please let me know if you need additional information!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is in the code behind.

Take the first drop down, find the field it is associated with, right click and create a "Changed" event.

In the code behind event, a Changed event will be created for that field. There you can grab the value of the currently selected item of the first drop down. Depending on that value, you can then modify the contents of the second drop down.

Do this by grabbing the original list, and running an SPQuery that selects all the items that have a "O" or "C" or whatever selected value is. You can also run a linq or foreach statement on all the list's items, whichever you prefer :)

Note: Make sure the drop down list control properties has "Always" selected in the Browser Forms tab of the properties (right click on the drop down list to access these properties)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Meyer. That was my original intent, and would be such an easy thing to do! However this is a Sharepoint List form rather than a Form Library form. List forms don't allow custom code (code behind) which is what threw a wrench into things for me. See the following for the differences between form types: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2010/04/22/comparing-list-and-form-library-forms.aspx